# Issue while uploading file in google drive with multi part settings using javascript rest apis (v2 and V3)

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, image-uploading

I want to upload a file to google drive with metadata, I am using the rest APIs and providing all the required details. The request is successfully completed, and files are created with the metadata, but the file size is just 13 byte.
here is the code

```
        function addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer, i) {


        var index = i;
        var fileName = files[index].name;
        const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
        const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
        const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";
        var fileContnet="this is the simple text file"
        const contentType = 'application/json';
        const contentTypeImage = 'application/octet-stream';
         var metadata = {
            'name': fileName,
            'mimeType': contentTypeImage

        };

         var multipartRequestBody =
            delimiter +
            'Content-Type:application/json \r\n\r\n' +
            JSON.stringify(metadata) +
            delimiter +
            'Content-Type: ' + contentTypeImage + '\r\n\r\n' +
            files[index] +
            close_delim;

//        var fileCollectionEndpoint ="https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart";



            var len=(arrayBuffer.byteLength);
            alert(len);
        var request = gapi.client.request({
        'path': '/upload/drive/v3/files',
        'method': 'POST',
        'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
        'headers': {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/related; boundary="' + boundary + '"',
          'Content-Length':len
        },
        'body': multipartRequestBody});

        request.execute(function(data){console.log(data)});
        //----------------------

    }
}
```

1. I tried various solutions.
2. I changed the arrayBuffer to files[i]
3. for Content-length I added (arrayBuffer.bytelength+metadata.lenght) 
   and (file[0].size+metadata.length)
   but no luck

**I tried a simple upload with no metadata, it works and a file is uploaded with untitled name.**

is there any one who faces the same issue and can sugggest me the solution

Comment: Check the [Multi-part upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/multipart-upload) docs, you might have missed a step like the order of the multipart uplaod request where metadata part comes first then the media part comes second.

Comment: Yes, I already did that, as you can see in the code the meta data is already added before the media